# Android Beacon Library RSSI filter

Tags: altbeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I know that this is related to existing question, but none directly answered my question, and my reputation is too low to add a comment to ask David.  Sorry :(

I'm using the Android Beacon Library, and I would like to experiment with filters besides the standard Running Average RSSI Filter and the ARMA filter.

Are there any guidelines that I should follow as I do this?  Are there any tips that I could use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to play with this you need to:

1. Build the Android Beacon Library from source.  (See the project README)
2. Make your own app (or use the library reference app) and point it at your custom liberty build.

Here are the basic commands to build from source within the reference app:

`git clone https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference.git
cd android-beacon-library-reference
git clone https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library.git`

Once you execute the above, simply edit the settings.gradle file to reference the library source folder by uncommenting this line: `include ':android-beacon-library'`, then edit the reference app's build.gradle file to reference the  library source folder instead of the binary -- uncomment: `compile project(':android-beacon-library')` and comment out: `compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+'`

After you have completed the above, verify you can build and run the reference app on your phone.  You can then make a copy of the org.altbeacon.beacon.service.RunningAverageRssiFilter.java file (giving it your own name in the same folder, perhaps MyRssiFilter.java). You can activate it by calling `BeaconManager.setRssiFilterImplClass(MyRssiFilter.class);`

Comment: Thank you David.  Actually, I made my own filter in my own folder, used the setRssiImpClass method, and all is working as expected.